How does wind on a mainsail lead to forward momentum?
Say we have a ship with a mainsail placed directly above the center of mass of the ship, and the relative velocity of the wind as seen from the sail is in the direction of motion of the ship.
Won't the force arising from the sail catching the wind be perpendicular to the line between the point of force and the center of mass? And in that case, won't all of the force translate into torque on the ship, and none into forward momentum? Does the buoyancy that keeps the ship from rotating lead to the forward acceleration? If yes, how does one calculate how much of the wind force leads to acceleration?
